# ASP.NET MVC two of 'the same' controller actions returning different views for different purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two controller actions, where one is used to return the view in a standard way and another returns a large chunk of the same view for use in, for example, a javascript modal somewhere else in my application. My question is what would be the best practise way to do this, or if the way I have done it is ok. Maybe I should move the duplicated code out to a helper method?

(Note the Create View has the _Create partial inside it)

Right now I have:

```
public ActionResult Create(int someParamater)
{
    //Lots of code 
    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult GetCreatePartial(int someParameter)
{
    //All of the same code as in Create
     return PartialView("_Create", model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on some condition and return `PartialView` or `View` on its basis, instead of creating a separate action:

```
public ActionResult Create(int someParamater)
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())   // check here if ajax call return partial
       return PartialView("_Create", model);
    else
       return View(model); // otherwise return Full View
}
```

Comment: `somecondition` could probably be `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`

Comment: With @Haim770's comment that makes a lot of sense. I'll have a go at implementing that and see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

If indeed your `GetCreatePartial` method can be called standalone, and the `someParameter` argument is available in the View as well, you can call it within parent view using `Html.Action()`.

For example (`Create.cshtml`):

```
<div>
    <span>some parent view stuff</span>
</div>

<div class="partial-wrapper">
    @Html.Action("GetCreatePartial", new { someParameter = Model.someParameter })
</div>
```

See [Html.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: My question was more about how to structure the controller in the best way

Comment: It should affect the way you're structuring the Controller as well as there's no need to fetch the model for the partial. In many cases it means that your `Create` method would only `return View(someParamater);`. Hard to provide full example when not enough code provided, but the core idea is that you can execute `GetCreatePartial` *method* (not as some partial rendering) from within parent view.

Comment: Understood, and that does make sense. Definitely valid.